# Ajax AutoComplete in the form form of gridview

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I'm having a textbox with ajax autocomplete extender

I'm extending TextBox1 with Ajax AutoComplete Extender and populating it with the help of WebService.

My requirement is that instead of a dropdown suggestion I should get a GridView like structure
with multiple columns with headers. I am using asp.net and ajaxcontrol toolkit

How can I achieve this?

Any help or suggestion.

```
public partial class AutoComplete : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetNames(string prefixText)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GridConnection"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select TOP 15 Name,Address,Grade from StudentDet where Name like @name+'%'", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", prefixText);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        List<string> ItemCodes = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ItemCodes.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()+""+dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()+" "+dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
        }
        return ItemCodes;
```

Markup is as follows

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function onListPopulated() {

    var completionList = $find("AutoCompleteEx").get_completionList();
    completionList.style.width = 'auto';
}
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<p>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAutoCmplte" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtAutoCmplte_AutoCompleteExtender" 
    runat="server" CompletionInterval="1" ServiceMethod="GetNames" 
    TargetControlID="txtAutoCmplte" 
        CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
        MinimumPrefixLength="1" BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx" 
        onclientpopulated="onListPopulated">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
</p>
<p>
</p>
</asp:Content>
    }
}
```

CSS is as follows

```
.autocomplete_completionListElement 
{   
    width:500px;
    margin : 0px!important;
    background-color : inherit;
    color : windowtext;
    border : buttonshadow;
    border-width : 1px;
    border-style : solid;
    overflow :auto;
    height : 200px;
    text-align : left; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a fair idea about your question. But what i thought is on the **textchange** event of the textbox **Fill Gridview** use grid view in **UpdatePanel**...and **trigger** a textchange event from the update panel so it will look like when you enter text in the textbox grid view auto fill on selection from grid view fill another textbox.

hope this help's.

will try to post code later..

EDIT:

Ok then 1 thing u can do ..

When you are returning your item list

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ItemCodes.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()+""+dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()+" "+dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
        }
```

use like this.

create a string first

```
string a = "<b><a href='"#"'> first col value </a></b> ;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp <b>a href='"#"'>second col</a></b> ;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp <b>a href='"#"'>third col</a></b>";
```

Then directly append this list of strings to dropdown div under your textbox so it will look like we have a grid view.. will post code at night that i have created this type of code on my site.

Comment: I mean something like this please refer this link http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multicolumncombo/defaultvb.aspx

Comment: Looking forward for more response from you

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
  $( "#autocompletePeople" ).autocomplete({
minLength: 0,
source: peoples,
focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#autocompletePeople" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#autocompletePeople" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
}
 })
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
return $( "<li></li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append( "<table><tr><td>" + item.label + "</td><td>" + item.desc + "</td></tr></table>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

where source people is the json object return from webservice

Comment: Can you please explain more. Is there anything to change int the CSS. I have updated the code with css and markup

Comment: css will be involved but you have to append table tags inside the render method when jquery is about to render the item